# Symfony2 : Sonata Admin Bundle. What is the persistence Service?

Tags: symfony, admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm deseperatly trying to make the Admin Bundle For several days now, and I'm stuck at some point.
I decided to re-start from the begining.

I've installed all the vendors conrrectly, and now, I can already access the admin dashboard by visiting the url: http://yoursite.local/admin/dashboard. (nothing much interesting in there, only the header.)

So on [step 2.2](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/getting_started.html#), they want me to Setup the persistence service (ORM, ODM, ...), I don't know what it is used for and, last time, since they say "SonataAdminBundle does not impose persistance service (service for handling and controlling your models)" I've skippedths step..... but maybe I shouldn t have done so ..

Could anyone tell me what it is used for please ?  should I use it, why and what for ? Maybe that's the reason why I can't make it work.

Thank You !

Comment: You might want to give AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle a try as well. Less people use it even though it appears to have less bugs and better support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out an important part of that quote...

> SonataAdminBundle does not impose persistance service (service for handling and controlling your models), **however most likely your application will use some persistance service (like ORM or ODM for database and document stores)**...

They're not saying you shouldn't use a persistence service, they're saying that the choice of *which* persistence service is up to you (should your app require it, and if your app uses a database, it's safe to say that it will require it).

> ...therefore you can use the following bundles officially supported by Sonata Project’s admin bundle:
>   - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle
>   - SonataDoctrineMongoDBAdminBundle
>   - SonataDoctrinePhpcrAdminBundle

I haven't used Sonata Admin bundle, but it definitely sounds like you shouldn't have skipped this step :-)

Comment: Haha I see, Well I just did, doesn't work better Thus, but at lest, I'm going in the right direction ! Thanks